# What is wrong with this JavaScript for loop? Is it the second statement that defines the condition?

Tags: javascript

```
var num = 5;

for (var i = 0; i > (num-1); i++) 
{
alert(i);
}
```

My understanding is that i will equal 0 at the start of the loop.
The check condition for the loop will be that it will run until i > 4.
(This is actually part of a bigger function where num will be passed into the function. So, I can't just use 4.)
Do I need to use a different operator instead of the minus sign?

When I run the code in a page I don't get any alerts.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: So, you're saying that it should be run as long as `i` is greater than `4`, and you begin with `0 > 4` which is false.

Comment: Your initial 5 conditions will always be false

Comment: Oh, duh...I have been working on this project too long. Time for a break. Geez...Sorry...delete this post...

Answer (score 4):

Your condition is wrong (should be < instead of >).

In your code `num = 5` and `i = 0`, so never the condition `0 > 4` is true.

So, your code should be

```
var num = 5;

for (var i = 0; i < (num - 1); i++) {
   console(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The check condition for the loop will be that it will run until i > 4

No. The loop will iterate **if** `i > (num-1)`.

At start, the loop will not run because `0 > 4` is not `true`.